# How to detect illegal UTF-8 byte sequences to replace them in java inputstream?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, inputstream, illegal-characters

The file in question is not under my control. Most byte sequences are valid UTF-8, it is not ISO-8859-1 (or an other encoding). 
I want to do my best do extract as much information as possible.

The file contains a few illegal byte sequences, those should be replaces with the replacement character.

It's not an easy task, it think it requires some knowledge about the UTF-8 state machine.

Oracle has a wrapper which does what I need:
[UTF8ValidationFilter javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10730/oracle/i18n/text/UTF8ValidationFilter.html)

Is there something like that available (commercially or as free software)?

Thanks
-stephan

Solution:

```
final BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(istream);
final CharsetDecoder charsetDecoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder();
charsetDecoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
charsetDecoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
final Reader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(in, charsetDecoder);
```

Comment: I hate this. content producers should produce valid content, not asking consumers to guess and correct. That has been causing so much trouble in our industry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) does what you need. This class provides charset decoding with user-definable actions on different kinds of errors (see [`onMalformedInput()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#onMalformedInput(java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction)) and [`onUnmappableCharacter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#onUnmappableCharacter(java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction))).

`CharsetDecoder` writes to an `OutputStream`, which you can pipe into an `InputStream` using [`java.io.PipedOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html), effectively creating a filtered `InputStream`.

Comment: @Henning - what if I want to know on which line there bad charachters?

Comment: @Dejel you could split the input in lines, and try to detect errors line per line.

Comment: Yes, splitting into lines would be the way to go, but this is usually implemented at the Reader level and not at the InputStream level, so you may have to dig around a bit or write your own.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to read the first few bytes to check Byte Order Mark (if exists). More information on BOM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark In the given url, you will find a table of the BOM bytes. However, one problem is, UTF-8 does not require to use BOM in its' header. There is another way to solve the problem is by pattern recognition (read few bytes-8 bits each time). Anyway, this is the complicated solution..

Comment: The Problem was not a BOM, it was already remove. There ist a BOMStripperInputStream floating around, which helps here: http://code.google.com/p/train-graph/source/browse/trunk/src/org/paradise/etrc/data/BOMStripperInputStream.java?r=31

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you want is already the default for `InputStreamReader`. So there is no need to specify it yourself. This suffices:

```
final BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(istream);
final Reader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```